# PHP/Postgres query not writing to CSV

Tags: php, postgresql, email, csv

I am having some trouble getting a postgres query to work within some php that I am running.  Essentially I am creating a daily report that will be emailed to a distribution list, but I can't get my data to pull into the csv.  This is something I have not done before so I've been using another similar report to get it this far.  Can someone please help?

```
include('/some_connection/db_connect.inc');

ob_flush();

$yesterday_db = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days'));
$yesterday_msg = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('-1 days'));
$yesterday_fn = date('Ymd', strtotime('-1 days'));

$filename = 'fileData_'.$yesterday_fn.'.csv';

$path = '/tmp/';


$res = $db->getAll("SELECT tickets.order_number, tickets.customer_id, tickets.ticket_id, customers.email, (customers.first_name || ' ' || customers.last_name), customers.address_line_1, customers.address_line_2, customers.city, customers.state, customers.zip, (customers.first_name || ' ' || customers.last_name), customers.address_line_1, customers.address_line_2, customers.city, customers.state, customers.zip, customers.phone_1, customers.phone_2, customers.phone_3, contacts.notes
        FROM tickets, customers, contacts
        WHERE tickets.initial_call_date >= '$yesterday_db'
        AND tickets.initial_call_date <= '$yesterday_db'
        AND tickets.customer_id = customers.customer_id
        AND tickets.ticket_id = contacts.ticket_id");


$db2 = DB::connect('database');
$db2->setFetchMode(DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);

$handle = fopen($path.$filename,'w');

if(DB::isError($res)) { echo $res->getdebuginfo(); return;}
fwrite($handle,'"Account","Customer Code","Email","Bill Name","Bill Address 1","Bill Address 2","Bill City","Bill State","Bill Zip","Ship Name","Ship Address 1","Ship Address 2","Ship City","Ship State","Ship Zip","Phone 1","Phone 2","Phone 3","Description"'."\n");

foreach($res as $crow){
$id = $crow['customer_id'];
$res = $db->query("SELECT tickets.order_number, tickets.customer_id, tickets.ticket_id, customers.email, (customers.first_name || ' ' || customers.last_name) as bill_name, customers.address_line_1, customers.address_line_2, customers.city, customers.state, customers.zip, (customers.first_name || ' ' || customers.last_name) as ship_name, customers.address_line_1, customers.address_line_2, customers.city, customers.state, customers.zip, customers.phone_1, customers.phone_2, customers.phone_3, contacts.notes
        FROM tickets, customers, contacts
        WHERE tickets.initial_call_date >= '$yesterday_db'
        AND tickets.initial_call_date <= '$yesterday_db'
        AND tickets.customer_id = customers.customer_id
        AND tickets.ticket_id = contacts.ticket_id");

if(DB::isError($res)) { echo 'Error getting information for '.$id.'.'.$res->getdebuginfo()."\n"; return; }

$row = $res->fetchrow();

if(!empty($row)){
fwrite($handle,'"","'.$row['order_number'].'","'.$row['customer_id'].'","'.$row['ticket_id'].'","'.$row['email'].'","'.$row['bill_name'].'","'.$row['address_line_1'].'","'.$row['address_line_2'].'","'.$row['city'].'","'.$row['state'].'","'.$row['zip'].'","'.$row['ship_name'].'","'.$row['address_line_1'].'","'.$row['address_line_2'].'","'.$row['city'].'","'.$row['state'].'","'.$row['zip'].'","'.$row['phone_1'].'","'.$row['phone_2'].'","'.$row['phone_3'].'","'.$row['notes']."\n");
    } 
}

fclose($handle);

$to = 'someone@somemail.com';
$from = 'system@somemail.com';
$from_name = 'Daily Upload';
$replyto = '';
$subject = 'CSV for '.$yesterday_msg."\n";
$message = 'Attached is the ticket data for '.$yesterday_msg."\n";



mail_attachment($filename,$path,$to,$from,$from_name,$replyto,$subject,$message);


function remove_non_numeric($string) {
return preg_replace('/\D/', '', $string);
}


function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
$file = $path.$filename;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/csv; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";
if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
    echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
} else {
    echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
}
}?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the final code so that it can help someone else if they should need it.

```
<?php
include('/home/ ... some connection ... /db_connect.inc');
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

ob_flush();

$yesterday_db = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days'));
$yesterday_msg = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('-1 days'));
$yesterday_fn = date('Ymd', strtotime('-1 days'));
$today_db = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today'));

$qty = 1;
$amt = 0;
$status = "'Service'";


$filename = 'dispatchTrack_'.$yesterday_fn.'.csv';
$path = '/tmp/';

$db2 = DB::connect('odbc://connection');
$db2->setFetchMode(DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
    if (!$db2) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
    }

$handle = fopen($path.$filename,'w');


$query = "SELECT distinct (wo.work_order_id || '-' || t.order_number) AS order_number, wo.customer, 
(c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name) as bill_name, 
(c.address_line_1) as bill_address_1, (c.address_line_2) as bill_address_2, 
(c.city) as bill_city, (c.state) as bill_state, (c.zip) as bill_zip, 
(c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name) as ship_name, 
(c.address_line_1) as ship_address_1, (c.address_line_2) as ship_address_2, 
(c.city) as ship_city, (c.state) as ship_state, (c.zip) as ship_zip, 
(c.phone_1) as phone1, (c.phone_2) as phone2, (c.phone_3) as phone3, 
c.email, (p.item_id) AS model, (ppi.display_name || ' - ' || p.item_description) AS description, $qty, $amt, $status, (wo.visit_date) AS delivery_date,
(techs.dispatch_code) AS truck, (p.problem_description) AS order_detail 
FROM work_orders AS wo, customers AS c, tickets AS t, techs, problems AS p
JOIN pta_package_items AS ppi
ON p.item_id = ppi.item_id
WHERE c.customer_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT wo.customer
        FROM work_orders AS wo
        WHERE wo.date_created >= '$yesterday_db'
        AND wo.date_created < '$today_db')
AND wo.customer = c.customer_id
AND t.ticket_id = wo.ticket_id
AND p.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
AND techs.tech_id = wo.tech
AND wo.status = 1
ORDER BY order_number";

$result = pg_query($query) or die ('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

fputcsv($handle, array('Order Number','Customer Code','Bill Name','Bill Address1','Bill Address2','Bill City','Bill State','Bill Zip','Ship Name','Ship Address1','Ship Address2','Ship City','Ship State','Ship Zip','Phone1','Phone2','Phone3','Email','Model','Description','Quantity','Amount','Delivery Type','Delivery Date','Truck','Order Detail','Comment1','Comment2','Comment3'));

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) fputcsv($handle, $row, $delimeter = ',', $enclosure = '"');

fclose($handle);
```

... and the rest of the file is the same as it was.  Thanks again for those who commented I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with your if:

```
if(empty($row)){
    //Write here
}
```

Should be:

```
if(!empty($row)){
    //Write here
}
```

Also note that [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) is a really useful function in cases like this.

Edit: Another issue is your loop:

```
foreach($res as $crow){
   $id = $crow['customer_id'];
   $res = $db->query(query);
}
```

Note that after the first loop you're writing over the `$res` variable.

Comment: I was finally able to get this working using the fputcsv option mentioned.  Thank you so much for the getting me set in the right direction!